# How to pass along menu shortcuts from child widget holding focus in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qt4.8

I have a [QMainWindow](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmainwindow.html) with a menu bar, including menu items for Save, Open and Quit with the usual shortcuts.  It creates a QTableWidget that lists a bunch of different categories from which the user can choose (at his option).

If the user clicks into the [QTableWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidget.html) to change categories, the widget takes the focus.  That's mostly what I want, but unfortunately it *also* seems to steal the menu shortcuts, so that pressing Ctrl+S no longer triggers the save.

I experimented with `keyPressEvent` to solve this, but it seems like overkill even if I do get it working.  Isn't there a way to delegate all the control/menu keys back to the **QMainWindow** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an issue with how you are creating your `QMenuBar`. Here is an example that works just fine for me. The Save continues to function regardless of focus being in the table:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(640,480)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        menu = menuBar.addMenu("&File")
        action = menu.addAction("&Save", self.doAction)
        action.setShortcuts(QtGui.QKeySequence.Save)

        self.view = QtGui.QTableWidget(5,5)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def doAction(self):
        print "Save"
```